# Codecademy Battleship Change Board Starting Point Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I've been going through Codecademy's Python lessons. I enjoyed the Battleship game I created in one of the lessons, but one thing annoyed me. The player has to constantly keep in mind that the rows and columns count 0-4 rather than 1-5. I've already made an attempt to fix this, but I'm not sure if it's messing with my ship placement.

Here's my original code:

```
    from random import randint

    #Create 5x5 game board
    board = []

    for x in range(5):
        board.append(["O"] * 5)

    def print_board(board):
        for row in board:
            print " ".join(row)

    #Start game
    print "Let's play Battleship!"
    print_board(board)

    #Randomly place ship
    def random_row(board):
        return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

    def random_col(board):
        return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

    ship_row = random_row(board)
    ship_col = random_col(board)

    #Process player guesses max 4 turns
    for turn in range(4):
        print "Turn: %d" % (turn + 1)
        guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
        guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

        if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
            print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
            break
        else:
            if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
                print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
                print_board(board)
            elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
                print "You guessed that one already."
                print_board(board)
            else:
                print "You missed my battleship!"
                board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
                print_board(board)
        if turn > 2:
            print "Game Over"
```

Here's my attempt to change the board count:

```
    from random import randint

    #Create 5x5 game board
    board = ['dummy']

    for x in range(5):
        board.append(["O"] * 6)

    def print_board(board):
        for row in board:
            print " ".join(row[1:])

    #Start game
    print "Let's play Battleship!"
    print_board(board[1:])

    #Randomly place ship
    def random_row(board):
        return randint(1, len(board[1:]) - 1)

    def random_col(board):
        return randint(1, len(board[1:]) - 1)

    ship_row = random_row(board[1:])
    ship_col = random_col(board[1:])
    print "%d,%d" % (ship_row, ship_col)
    #Process player guesses max 4 turns
    for turn in range(4):
        print "Turn: %d" % (turn + 1)
        guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
        guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

        if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
            print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
            break
        else:
            if (guess_row < 1 or guess_row > 5) or (guess_col < 1 or guess_col > 5):
                print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
                print_board(board[1:])
            elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
                print "You guessed that one already."
                print_board(board[1:])
            else:
                print "You missed my battleship!"
                board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
                print_board(board[1:])
        if turn > 2:
            print "Game Over"
```

The `print "%d,%d" % (ship_row, ship_col)` is only in there so I can test the ship placement. I haven't seen a ship placed in a position higher than 3 on rows or columns. Not sure if I screwed the code or if it's just dumb luck. Any insight is appreciated and if you know an easier to accomplish this please let me know. I've been thinking `guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:")) - 1` but haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well sometimes the obvious answer is the right one. 
I changed:

```
    for turn in range(4):
        print "Turn: %d" % (turn + 1)
        guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
        guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))
```

To:

```
    for turn in range(4):
        print "Turn: %d" % (turn + 1)
        guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:")) - 1
        guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:")) - 1
```

This allows the player to enter a choice of 1-5 rather than 0-4